# Python modulenotfounderror from command line

Tags: python, import, module

I have looked up solutions online for this issue, but none of them seem to address my specific situation.

I have a pycharm project with multiple directories, subdirs and files. When I invoke the main entry point method from the command line, I get 
ModuleNotFoundError on all the imports across ~20 files. The solutions I found online recommend modifying the PYTHONPATH. This is not a viable solution for my use case because

1. I would have to add the sys.path.append call in all my files. That's the only way that it seems to work.
2. I cannot use any third party libs.
3. I will be sharing the project as a zip file. Note: I cannot use github to share the project nor is my intention to create a distributable. So when someone else unzips the project on their PC, they should be able to run it from the command line with out any issues. They should not have to modify their env variables to run it.

What are my options?

EDIT:

Project structure:

```
Project-
        |
        | 
     mod-
         |
         |
       data-
           |
           |
        ClassA.py
        ClassB.py
           |
     config-
           |
           |
       ClassC.py
       ClassD.py
         ...
   main.py
```

Import statements look like this:

```
from mod.data.ClassA import ClassA
```

Error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ClassA'
```

This error shows up for every import statement in my python files.

When I add sys.path.append it works, but I have to do it for every import statement and its a hard coded abs path that will need to be updated by anyone with the zip.

Comment: It is hard to say anything without seeing your project structure and the failing imports. You may have a look at relative imports.

Comment: @Selcuk, edited OP.

Comment: Is your main Python file always in the same location relative to your other files?  If so, you could compute an absolute path by starting with the path of the main file and then using "/.." and dir names to get to the module you wish to add via sys.path.append() . You would only need to make that call once as I expect that all of your imports are from the root of your module.

The way this is normally handled is to bundle your code as a Python module that is installed by pip or easy_install.  Then all the path stuff is handled for you as the module is installed into the standard module tree.

Comment: I only just noticed the main.py file in your project structure.  If that file contains your main entrypoint, and if the files are always together like that, you should be able to use relative imports and not have to modify the module search path at all.

Answer (score 0):

If your modules are contained in the same directory as your executable, as you seem to indicate, it's this simple:

File structure:

```
f1.py
m1
  __init__.py
  C1.py
```

C1.py

```
class C1:
    def test(self):
        print("Hi!")
```

f1.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from m1.C1 import C1

C1().test()
```

Execution:

```
> python f1.py
Hi!
```

You do have __init__.py files in your module directories, right?  If not, then that's probably why you're having trouble with this.